# Booting but not rebooting from external USB hard drive, what could be the problem?

Tags: 10.10, boot, usb-drive, bios

I have a Dell Inspiron 6400 laptop with a dead internal hard drive controller. It boots perfectly from CD or USB. I therefore removed the internal hard drive and installed Ubuntu 10.10 Maverick onto an external USB hard drive.

It boots and runs perfectly when doing a "cold start" of the PC. However, when I choose restart/reboot in the Ubuntu menu (e.g. after an update), I get this error message from the BIOS: "No bootable devices, strike <kbd>F1</kbd> to retry boot, <kbd>F2</kbd> for setup utility, press <kbd>F5</kbd> to run onboard diagnostics". I can make the system boot again by pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>F5</kbd> and exiting the utility without having done anything. Or, I can simply power off the system and do a new "cold start".

Does anyone know the likely reason for this problem and how to fix it. It is not a big issue but an annoyance that I would like to fix if possible.

Comment: This is most likely a BIOS/HW issue, probably the USB device is  powered off during the shutdown and the power is not restored during the hot restart.

Comment: I have a similar issue... but instead, it doesnt reboot even from a "cold start". I must unplug and replug the USB stick so it boots again. Any hints? http://askubuntu.com/questions/47459

Answer (score 4):

Use an additional power supply for your USB hard drive. Most hard disks need more then 500mW at spin up time. This may lead to a problem if Linux suspend the USB device at shutdown.